# data control available (in .NET) for a complex object (object with children objects)

Tags: asp.net

Is there any data control available (in .NET) for a complex object (object with children objects). Something like a gridview but with hiperlinks which will take you to child object.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest ListView (or gridview if that makes sense for the scenario). There is also a treeview control.

Check this question for an example of the nested listview (it uses IGrouping, but the concept is the same - just set the DataSource to the Childs Property ): [Displaying an IGrouping<> with nested ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172934/displaying-an-igrouping-with-nested-listviews)

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Dynamic Data. [www.asp.net/dynamicdata/](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/)