# How To Use ObjectDataSource With Complex Objects and FormView Control

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, objectdatasource

I have a complex object.  For example a SCHOOL object that contains a collection of PERSON object.  How can I use the ObjectDataSource control with a FormView and flatten the complex object?  An example display would be to display the school name and comma separate the students on the page.  Is this possible?

I.E.
public string Id
{
get { return m_id; }
set { m_id = value; }
}

public string SchoolName
{
  get { return m_schoolName; }
  set { m_schoolName = value; }
}

public List(Person> Students
{
get { return m_students; }
set { m_cast = students; }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[Displaying an IGrouping<> with nested ListViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172934/displaying-an-igrouping-with-nested-listviews).

I nested a DataList control inside my FormView control to get it working.